# Groupy by first column and display as column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I looked around for quite a while and can't seem to find the right answer.

I am trying to group by first column (name), then display the result as column. Any help will be appreciated.

I am new to programming, any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

currently displayed

```
        name    data

0   LAST_1  106.305

1   LAST_DATE_1 20180401

2   LAST_TIME_1 145507000

3   LAST_1  106.256

4   LAST_DATE_1 20180401

5   LAST_TIME_1 155946000

6   LAST_1  106.225

7   LAST_DATE_1 20180401

8   LAST_TIME_1 165947000

9   LAST_1  106.264

10  LAST_DATE_1 20180401

11  LAST_TIME_1 175957000

12  LAST_1  106.303

13  LAST_DATE_1 20180401

14  LAST_TIME_1 185956000

... ... ...
```

expected result

```
LAST_1    LAST_DATE_1     LAST_TIME_1

106.342   20180401        235957000

106.321   20180401        215959000
```

Comment: What hvae you tried so far?  Please show your code.

Answer (score 2):

You want a pivot here. You could use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) and build the index taking the [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) from the `name`:

```
i = df.groupby(df.name).cumcount()
df.pivot_table(index=i, columns=df.name)

 data                         
name   LAST_1 LAST_DATE_1  LAST_TIME_1
0     106.305  20180401.0  145507000.0
1     106.256  20180401.0  155946000.0
2     106.225  20180401.0  165947000.0
3     106.264  20180401.0  175957000.0
4     106.303  20180401.0  185956000.0
5     106.321  20180401.0  195957000.0
6     106.282  20180401.0  205950000.0
7     106.342  20180401.0  215959000.0
8     106.317  20180401.0  225956000.0
9     106.361  20180401.0  235957000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.groupby()` on the first column and `apply` a list on the second one, then using this create a dataframe and transpose:

```
m=df.groupby('name')['data'].apply(list)
m=pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index=m.index).T.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print(m)
```

---

```
    LAST_1  LAST_DATE_1  LAST_TIME_1
0  106.305   20180401.0  145507000.0
1  106.256   20180401.0  155946000.0
2  106.225   20180401.0  165947000.0
3  106.264   20180401.0  175957000.0
4  106.303   20180401.0  185956000.0
5  106.321   20180401.0  195957000.0
6  106.282   20180401.0  205950000.0
7  106.342   20180401.0  215959000.0
8  106.317   20180401.0  225956000.0
9  106.361   20180401.0  235957000.0
```